# Inserting struct slice into Postgresql jsonb[]

Tags: json, postgresql, go

I have a struct slice that I'm trying to marshal into a json array for insert into a postgresql database with a column type of jsonb[].

```
type t struct {
    A int
    B string
}
a := t{1, "hello"}
b := t{2, "goodbye"}

var c []t
c = append(c, a, b)

bytes, _ := json.Marshal(c)

stmt := `INSERT INTO test (s, ja) VALUES ($1, $2)`
_, err = db.Exec(stmt, "test", bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Insert error:", err)
}
```

I get the error:

> pq: malformed array literal: "[{"A":1,"B":"hello"},{"A":2,"B":"goodbye"}]"

How can I make the data appropriate for a jsonb[] column?

Comment: Change your table column definition, `jsonb[]` is not a json array, but a *postgres array* of json data. Change it to just `jsonb` and see what happens.

Comment: You could also change your code and not call `json.Marshal(c)` and instead marshal a and b separately and then add them into an array and then pass that array

Comment: Also I can recommend check postgresql logs to see whole query - possibly it contains errors.

Comment: @mkopriva just saved me from 2 days of spiraling down. The solution helped me. Also, for future ref: https://github.com/jackc/pgx/v4 is very useful.